# Symfony security system, redirect loop (need to access the user in every page)?

Tags: security, authentication, symfony, symfony-2.1, silex

I need to access the current user logged in (if any) in any part of the application. Special paths like `/admin` requires special permissions (roles).

This is the firewall configuration (just one firewall) **protecting the entire application** but **not allowing anonymous** users (because I need the current user even in homepage).

I got a redirect loop even requesting `/`. Any help?

```php
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '.*',
        'anonymous' => false,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/login_check',
            'username_parameter' => 'login[username]',
            'password_parameter' => 'login[password]',
        ),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout')
    )
)
```

Access rules requires `ROLE_ADMIN` only for paths starting with `/admin` . The rest is anonymous:

```
'security.access_rules' => array(
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    array('^.*',     'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
),
```

Answer (score 2):

To allow acces via `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` have have to allow anonymous.

```
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '/',
        'anonymous' => true,
        // other stuff
    )
)

'security.access_rules' => array(
    array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    array('^/',      'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
),
```

If the user is logged in you can access them in every page. `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` is only a role, which have unauthenticated users (anonymous).